# Inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ using Fermat's Theorem or its corollaries.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is $3^{-1}$ , the multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Use Fermat's Theorem or its collaries.

How do I make use of the Fermat's theorem to solve this?
I know how to solve it using Linear Diophantine Equations and the EEA only

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fermat states $3^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$, therefore $3\cdot 3^5 \equiv 1 \pmod 7.$
Can you continue?

Comment: But 3^5 is a really big number. Is there a trick to make it between 0 and 7

Comment: $3^5=3^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 3\equiv 2\cdot 2\cdot 3\pmod 7$. If you reduce your **big number** modulo 7, it will eventually lie between 0 and 6, both included.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By Fermat's if $a\nmid p$

$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$

So, $3\cdot 3^5=3^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$